# Как проверить, во всех ли директориях, прописанных в PATH, есть исполняемые файлы? И как удалить неисполняемые?

Tags: linux, path

Проверить нужно в командной строке

Comment: Интересно зачем бы такое могло понадобится. Если папка PATH пуста, это не значит что по ней надо принимать какие то решения, ибо удаление может привести в последствии к невозможности установки каких нибудь пакетов. Да и удалять неисполнимые файлы просто так нельзя, они могут быть частью исполнимых. Да и писать такое муторно. И imho лучше не на шелле, а не перле например.

Comment: Вот у меня например на gentoo во всех каталогах PATH присутствует файл с именем `.keep`, он не выполнимый. Но его наличие необходимо emerge, менеджеру установки пакетов, что бы он знал, что такой каталог удалять никогда нельзя

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Как проверить, во всех ли директориях, прописанных в PATH, есть исполняемые файлы?

например, так:

```
$ for d in $(echo $PATH | sed 's/:/ /g'); do \
 r=$(find $d -type f -executable | wc -l); [ $r -eq 0 ] && \
 { echo "не во всех. например, тут нет: $d"; break; }; done
```

пример вывода:

```
не во всех. например, тут нет: /opt/bin
```

> И как удалить неисполняемые?

неисполняемые файлы можно удалить, как и любые другие файлы, например, программой `rm`:

```
$ rm /путь/к/удаляемому/файлу
```